# deleting last character from span text?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a span element which is just text. I keep on appending to it based on certain events. That works fine using `$("#id").append(txt);`. I am however not able to delete from it. I tried using `$("#id").slice(0, -1)` as well as `$("#id").val().slice(0, -1);`
The values displayed on the page remain the same. Should I be using `substr` or something?
Tried google but couldn't come up with anything like this? Is this even possible using jquery?

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the last four characters or just the last character? `.slice(0,-1)` is for the last character, `.slice(0,-4)` is for the last four.

Comment: @Luxelin. edited to remove the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like [this](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function):

```
$(selector).text(function(i,v){
   return v.slice(0,-4);
});
```

Comment: I particularly like this feature of jQuery :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy How so? An id selector only yields at most a single element, I don't see how that affects its feasibility.

Comment: @C-link, i am a novice on this so for my case it should be `$("#id").text(function(i, v){ return v.slice(0, -4); };`. This should change the span text?

Answer (score 0):

Try this after appending this line `$("#id").append(txt);`

```
var str = $("#id").text(); // this hold appended text
alert(str.substring(0,str.length - 1));
```

OR

```
str.slice(0,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

actualy, with **slice()** you can do it even easier:

```
var originalText = $("#id").text();
var result = originalText.slice(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the text, take its substring trimming the last character, and then again put the value to the `#id`

```
$k = $('#id').text();
$k.substring(0,$k.length-1);
$('#id').text($k);
```